# Apache redirect only working with index.php and not without?

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

I have the same instance of laravel running on two different machines. They both have the same .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The one system is running PHP 5.5, and the other PHP 5.4. The problem is, this works on the one system but not the other:

```
http://www.example.com/register
```

However, this works on both:

```
    http://www.example.com/index.php/register
```

What possible htaccess could there be that causes it to only work with index.php? I need it to work without index.php as well?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use `RewriteBase /` above `RewriteEngine On` if there is an inconsistency between the systems in what the root url is

Comment: Only problem is, now the OTHER system thay was working is automatilly redirecting to /, when the actual path is /something-else?